# DataGridView: What is the best approach to handle Editable Data in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

What is the best approach to handle editable DataGridView (DGV)

**Goals:**

What I need to achieve is whatever amount is inputted in amount column, the Balance Column will be updated.
Compute the total amount entered by the user in the DGV and set it to payment amount textbox.

[image]

**Object Class:**

```
class Invoice
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int invoice_id { get; set; }
    public string invoicenumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public DateTime due_date{ get; set; }
    public decimal total_gross { get; set; }
    public bool is_service { get; set; }
    public int customer_id { get; set; }
    public List<Invoice> invoices = new List<Invoice>();
    // and other properties

    public decimal get_invoice_balance(decimal payment_amount)
    {
        return total_gross - payment_amount;
    }

    public List<Invoice> read(string where_query)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "SELECT invoice.id as id,invoicenumber,name,date,due_date,account_name,remarks,total_gross,invoice_id FROM invoice ";
            query += "LEFT JOIN customer ON customer.customer_id = invoice.customer_id ";
            query += "LEFT JOIN account ON account.account_id = invoice.ar_account_id "; 

            conn.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company_id", Variables.Company_ID);

            if (where_query != null && where_query.Length > 0)
            {
                query += where_query;
            }else
            {
                query += "WHERE invoice.company_id = @company_id ";
            }

            query += "ORDER BY invoice_id ";

            conn.OPEN(query);

            while (conn.reader.Read())
            {
                Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
                invoice.id = Int32.Parse(conn.reader["id"].ToString());
                invoice.invoice_id = Int32.Parse(conn.reader["invoice_id"].ToString());
                invoice.invoicenumber = (string)conn.reader["invoicenumber"];
                invoice.customer_name = Global_Functions.object_to_string(conn.reader["name"]);
                invoice.date = Convert.ToDateTime(conn.reader["date"]).Date;
                invoice.due_date = Convert.ToDateTime(conn.reader["due_date"]).Date;
                invoice.ar_account_name = Global_Functions.object_to_string(conn.reader["account_name"]);
                invoice.remarks = Global_Functions.object_to_string(conn.reader["remarks"]);
                invoice.total_gross = (decimal)conn.reader["total_gross"];

                invoices.Add(invoice);
            }

            conn.CLOSE();

            return invoices;

        } catch (Exception err)
        {
            Global_Functions.open_error_dialog(err.Message.ToString());
            return invoices;
        }
    }      

}
```

**Populating the DataGridView** - I Manually added columns in the DataGridView and name it according to the class property

```
List<Invoice> invoices = new Invoice().read(null);

foreach (Invoice invoice_item in invoices)
{
            DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dgv_invoices.Rows[0].Clone();
            row.Cells[0].Value = invoice_item.id;
            row.Cells[1].Value = invoice_item.invoicenumber;
            row.Cells[2].Value = invoice_item.date;
            row.Cells[3].Value = invoice_item.due_date;
            row.Cells[4].Value = invoice_item.total_gross;
            row.Cells[5].Value = invoice_item.get_invoice_balance(Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[6].Value));
            row.Cells[6].Value = 0;
            row.Tag = invoice_item;
            dgv_invoices.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

**Populating DataGrid with DataSource** - If i populate the DataGridView like this then it would be easy to cast the row as an invoice object. But the issue is i have to manually set the unwanted columns not to show instead of just selecting the columns i want to show. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
List<Invoice> invoices = new Invoice().read(null);
dgv_invoices.DataSource = invoices;
```

[image]

**Trigger Function**

```
private void dgv_invoices_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
      if(dgv_invoices.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Amount")
      {                       
            // Cast the Datagridrow into an Object Invoice, this works if i populate the datagridview with dgv_invoices.Datasouce = invoices;
            Invoice invoice = (Invoice)dgv_invoices.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;


            // use the instance to compute, (Note: I need to put the computations in the class so it would be easy to reuse the code and manage it)
            decimal balance = invoice.get_invoice_balance("Amount inputted in Amount Cell")

            // Update the Cell in Column
            dgv_invoices.CurrentRow.Cell = balance;

            // Update Payment Amount based on the list - Pseudo
            tx_payment_amount.Text = function_to_compute_total();
      }
 }
```

Please feel free to ask questions, criticize any of my code or comment any confusion so I could correct and improve my explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that in C# you write CamelCase for Methods and Properties: `GetInvoiceBalance()` or `AccountName`. Further instead of looping you can set the Property `dataGridView.DataSource`. Possible DataSources are DataTables and all types of IList implementation so far I know. So you can do following:

```
List<Invoice> invoices = new Invoice().Read(null);
dataGridView.DataSource = invoices;
```

Changes to your DataSource will be reflected into the Grid. So you can define the getter of your Balance-Property like:

```
public int Balance {get {return Amount + 10;}}
```

So if you edit the amount, the grid automatically update the Balance to your Amount + 10. Notice that a `dataGridView.Refresh()`is needed maybe.

You noticed that the Grid will populate every Property as a Column. If you don't want this you can add columns by your own. You can define them in Designer or directly in code:

```
DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewColumn();
col.DataPropertyName = nameof(Invoice.Amount); //This binds the value to your column
col.HeaderText = "Amount";
col.Name = "Amount";
dgViewStudents.Columns.Add(col);
```

So you can create the columns you need and the Grid won't populate a column for every Property which is the default behaviour.

The last step would be to compute the total amount. I would recommend to use the DataSource as much as possible and let the view just doing view-stuff.  Your DataSource is the `List<Invoice>` you created. So adding `INotifyPropertyChanged` to your Invoice-Class would be a nice approach.

```
class Invoice : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _amount;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Amount 
    {
       get{return _amount;}
       set
       {
          _amount = value;
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Amount)))
       }
    }
}
```

You should do this for every Property. A bit of boilerplate this Interface so if you are interested in getting this better use [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/).

Now you can change your `List<Invoice>` to `BindingList<Invoice>` and apply this to your Grid. The BindingList allows you to be Notified if some Element is changed. Register the ListChanged-Event for this. Notice that you must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to be notified about Element-Changes. Else you are just notified about new items or removed items.

```
 BindingList<Invoice> invoices = new Invoice.Read(null);
 invoices.ListChanged += Invoice_ListChanged;

 private void Test_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
    {
       //Calculate Amount and populate to TextBox (invoices is your DataSource)
       textBoxSum.Text = invoices.Sum(invoice => invoice.Amount);
    }
 }
```

Further I would recommend you to make the `Read();` static. So you can call it like this:

```
Invoice.Read();
```

instead of:

```
new Invoice.Read();
```

It's because I think one specific Invoice-Object has nothing to do with reading invoices. I hope you know what I mean. Reading is not object specific.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you!, this will really help me a lot.